# Fully vectorise sum of binned data (using pre-computed bin-index)

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that I have some time series (`t`) with multiple observables (`a` and `b`):

```py
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
a = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=0.1, size=t.size)
b = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.5, size=t.size)
```

I want to get the mean of time-bins, e.g.:

```py
bin_edges = np.linspace(0, 12, 12)
bin_index = np.digitize(t, bin_edges) - 1
a_binned = np.zeros(bin_edges.size - 1)
b_binned = np.zeros(bin_edges.size - 1)

for ibin in np.argwhere(np.bincount(bin_index) > 0).flatten():
    select = bin_index == ibin
    a_binned[ibin] = np.mean(a[select])
    b_binned[ibin] = np.mean(b[select])
```

**My question: (How) can I vectorise the loop?**

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950231/group-by-with-numpy-mean

Comment: Since the bin size varies, `a[select]` has different values for each edge, and this can't be "vectorized" - at least not in the conventional sense.  That is, we can't make a "rectangular" array and take the `mean` of rows.  As the above link shows there are some ways around this, but in general, `pandas` is better for 'groupby' actions.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for making the issue explicit, I failed to write that ;). A question to both of you, I'm not entirely sure what an algorithm with `reduceat` would look like? Also, how would it compare with the efficiency of the algorithm posted below, which for dense data is two order of magnitude faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b, 'index':bin_index})
gp = df.groupby('index').mean()
```

You can extract the np arrays back like:

```
a_binned = gp.a.values
b_binned = gp.b.values
```

### Only with numpy:

Another solution, a bit more complex that uses only numpy and no loops, but assumes that your bins are in order and indexed by an integer count (like your case):

```
indexes = np.argwhere(np.diff(bin_index, prepend=0, append=1)).flatten()
len_of_index = np.diff(indexes, prepend=0)
indexes = indexes -1 # array python index starts at 0

cumsum = np.cumsum(a)[indexes]
sum_groups = np.diff(cumsum, prepend=0)
means = sum_groups/len_of_index
```

The idea behind that is making the cumulative sum and then the difference just to latter divide by the number of occurrences.

Finally you can also add multiple arrays at once, and make a convenient function:

```
array = np.array([a,b])
def binned_mean(array, bin_index):
    indexes = np.argwhere(np.diff(bin_index, prepend=bin_index[0], append=1)).flatten()
    len_of_index = np.diff(indexes, prepend=0)
    indexes = indexes -1 # array python index starts at 0

    cumsum = np.cumsum(array, axis=1)[:, indexes]
    sum_groups = np.diff(cumsum, prepend=0)
    
    # taking care of possible holes in the binning
    means = np.empty([np.shape(array)[0], max(bin_index)+1])
    means[:] = np.nan
    means[:, bin_index[indexes]] = sum_groups/len_of_index # bin_index[indexes] -> present idexes
    return means

binned_mean(array, bin_index)
```

The numpy solution turns out to be way faster (around 100x) but pandas is still more legible and battle tested, in special it doesn't make the assumptions i made for the numpy solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That is a very nice algorithm! I found two edge cases: 1) the first bin is not 0 (fix: `prepend= bin_index[0]`), 2) 'holes' (empty bins) (fix: store to `means[bin_index[indexes]]`). Do you want: a) to edit, b) me to edit, c) me to add an answer? Ref: https://github.com/tdegeus/enstat/pull/33/files

Comment: @TomdeGeus good points, I have just corrected them, good that you liked the solution.